# NASM windows, output binary

Tags: windows, assembly, nasm

Lets say i have the following:

```
output: db 1Eh
```

in binary it is 11110

i would like to print out "#### "
how would i do this i understand i would need to some how step through it in a loop but i am struggling thinking of what commands i would need to call to load each bit into a seperate register so i can compare if it is 1 or 0 and output the needed character.

im using NASM and on a windows xp running it using 16 bits.

thanks in advanced.

EDIT---
here is some code i am currently testing though it completely does not work

```
bits 16
            org 0x100
            jmp main
dollar:     db "$"
hash:       db "#"

printd:
            mov dx,dollar
            call disply
            ret
printh:
            mov dx,hash
            call disply
            ret             
disply:     mov ah,09h  ;This function displays what is currently in the DX register 
            int 21h
            ret
main:
            mov ax,1Eh
            mov bx,5

            shl ax,10
loop1:      shl ax,1
            JB printd
            JAE printh
            sub bx,1
            JNS loop1   

            int 20h
```

Comment: `shl` will put a bit in the carry flag. Then `adc` to make a '0' or '1'.

Comment: Re: your edited code...`int 21h/9` isn't going to print a '$'... and isn't going to stop after '#' unless you put a '$' there. Better `int 21h/1`? You jump to some routines that end in `ret`. That isn't going to work, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example:

```
    BITS 16
    ORG 100h

        mov cx, 8

    _Loop:
        shl byte [output], 1
        setc dl
        add dl, 30h
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        loop _Loop

        mov ax, 4C00h
        int 21h

    output: db 1Eh
```

Another Example:

```
    BITS 16
    ORG 100h

        bsr cx, [output]

    _Loop:
        bt [output], cx
        mov dl, '0'
        adc dl, 0
        mov ah, 02h
        int 21h
        sub cl, 1
        jnc _Loop

        mov ax, 4C00h
        int 21h

    output: dw 1Eh
```

Comment: Thanks mate your code helped me get to my final code.

Answer (score 0):

rkhb's code helped out but finally i got it right, it might be considered a hack but it does what i need it to do

```
bits 16
jmp main

axbinout:
    push cx
    push dx
    mov cx, 5
.top:
    rcr ax, 1 ; Rotate and set the carry with what we rotated off
    push ax ; Save AX

    mov dl, ' ' ; Set DL to "0", the default value
    mov al, 4 ; the offset the dollar sign is from space
    mov bl, 0 ;setting bl to zero
    adc bl, 0 ; adding the carry bit to bl 
    mul bl ; multiplying it by the offset set in al

    add dx,ax ; adding ax to dx
    mov ah, 0x0A ; 0x0A is the "print byte at cursor" argument to INT 0x10
    mov al, dl ; Our result is in DL, but INT 0x10 uses AL
    int 0x10 ; Print the byte
    pop ax ; Restore AX

    loop .top

    pop dx
    pop cx
    ret

main:
    mov ax, 1Eh
    call axbinout
    int 20h
```